# decimal parameter using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, read-csv

I have a CSV with 19 columns. Many of the values are decimals formatted like '56,2' [german/eureopean format]. No big issue, I thought using the 'decimal=' parameter:

```
self.imported_csv = pd.read_csv(full_path, encoding='utf_16_le', sep=';', on_bad_lines='warn', decimal=',')
```

Works fine - except for exactly ONE column. So every other column is read correctly (floats), but the ONE columns keeps the ',' as decimal seperator. Any idea why this is possible?

Not knowing why, I tried following workaround:

```
self.imported_csv['Luftdruck (hPa)'] = self.imported_csv['Luftdruck (hPa)'].astype(float)
```

... unfortunately I already expected the result: could not convert string to float: '979,5'.

Any idea what problem I am facing here? Thanks in advance.

Here is one example row of the CSV:

[image: one example row]

Comment: Could you please share what the raw file looks like?

Comment: Please don't put a solution in the question. Answers should go in the answers section, so you can [write your own answer](/help/self-answer) if you want, or leave it if TheHungryCub's answer suffices. I removed it and added back the example data, but you can refer back to the [edit history](/posts/77851754/revisions) if needed.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341); post the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code) or [table formatting](/editing-help#tables). It'd also help to provide data that reproduces the issue; for reference see [mre]. This data doesn't seem to have any values with two periods like you wrote, `1.000.1`. Or, now that I mention it, did you mean a comma followed by a period, `1,000.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before reading the CSV, you might consider cleaning the problematic column to remove any non-numeric characters or inconsistencies.

```
self.imported_csv['Luftdruck (hPa)'] = self.imported_csv['Luftdruck (hPa)'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```

Try explicitly specifying the locale using the locale parameter in the read_csv function:

```
self.imported_csv = pd.read_csv(full_path, encoding='utf_16_le', sep=';', on_bad_lines='warn', decimal=',', thousands='.', locale='de_DE')
```

Also please ensure below points :

1. Look for any non-numeric characters in the column. There might be invisible characters or non-breaking spaces that are causing the issue.
2. Look for any non-numeric characters in the column. There might be invisible characters or non-breaking spaces that are causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks, Suraj! That helped! The missing thousands-parameter is the solution. After Replacing (I tried this as well) the parser found something like "1.000.4" and could not resolve this. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanBongers You're Welcome! Cheers! (you can accept answer so that it will helpful for others :) )

Answer (score 0):

Quite possible there's some string values in that column, I'd check for things like "NAN" or something that wouldn't otherwise be parsed.

I would try the following and see if that works:

```
imported_csv["Luftdruck (hPa)"] = imported_csv["Luftdruck (hPa)"].str.replace(",",".").astype(float)
```

Otherwise check the column for non-parseable values like actual strings.